# Selecting a sliding patio door

Tags: doors, product-recommendation, patio, replacement, outdoor

I live in the Boulder Colorado area where we have hot intense sunny summer days, and below zero freezing winter nights. We are planning to install a sliding patio door in a south facing full sun area. I am also concerned about damage to the outdoor frame, as our current sliding door leaks during intense rain storms due to cracked seals and weathering.

What are some of the things I should look for when searching for the new sliding door?

Answer (score 2):

- Double-glazed (toughened safety glass) without question.
- Possibly tented glass (would help a little on those intense summer days).
- uPVC frame (and uPVC trim pieces). uPVC doesn't seem that popular here in the USA (at least here in the St Louis area), but in the UK it is extremely popular (mainly due to its almost zero maintenance requirements).
- Built in anti-lift device/mechanism.
- Good quality hardware & locks.

Comment: I would use laminated glass rather than toughened, as when toughened class breaks it is easy to remove the bits as they are not sharp.   Laminated glass holds together when it breaks, so makes it a lot harder for someone to break in.

Comment: @Walker, you make a very! good and valid point, but please allow me to play a little devils advocate here :) Laminated glass is generally thicker than toughened glass, therefore heavier, which it turn _normally_ make it more expensive, plus will put greater wear & tear on the patio door hardware (sliding mechanism). Also having toughened glass in an external door will allow it to be broken easier in the case of an emergency (eg house fire). Personally I think the choice between the 2 options is swings & roundabouts, and really does come down to personal preference. Both will work just fine.